# Listing Child terms on clicking parent terms in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have made one taxonomy of faq and in that I have added terms in the format:
Parent 1:
            Child 1
            Child 2
Parent 2:
            Child 3
            Child 4
Parent 3
Parent 4:
            Child 5
So, as you can see, there are no child terms for Parent 3.

I made one view, in that I was able to show Parent terms. But I want to relate these parent terms to the respective child terms. For example, if I clicked on Parent 1, it should take me to the Child1 and Child 2 listing, then if I clicked on any of them, they would take me to the respective questions that I have added.
I researched and found out that this can only be done with relationship. So, if somebody knows the steps, mention them or guide me if I am wrong.

Thanks